# XSLT wrap group of nodes with new parent

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XPath expression which works fine on XML files to select all nodes that contain a certain attribute, 'Culture'.  These appear in groups of 5 in the same order throughout the document.

I need to group these 5 nodes and surround them with a new parent node set. Some of these groups already have a parent node, the others do not.

I have tried using current-group() and failed dismally, any pointers would be gratefuly received.

Here is the expression that finds all the nodes, I'm sure it can be shortened but it works.
     //*[@Culture='de-DE']|//*[@Culture='es-ES']|//*[@Culture='fr-CA']|//*[@Culture='it-IT']|//*[@Culture='en-CA']

Here is a short snippet of XML , the actual files are nearly 200,000 characters and these nodes are heavily nested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Survey Id="y77343555"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance.xsd" >
<Xflow>
    <Answer Code="4">           
            <Text Culture="en-CA">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="fr-CA">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="es-ES">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="de-DE">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="it-IT">34</Text>
    </Answer>               
            <InstructionText Culture="en-CA">34</InstructionText>
            <InstructionText Culture="fr-CA">34</InstructionText>
            <InstructionText Culture="es-ES">34</InstructionText>
            <InstructionText Culture="de-DE">34</InstructionText>
            <InstructionText Culture="it-IT">34</InstructionText>                       
    <Answer Code="45">
        <Route Code="12">               
            <Text Culture="en-CA">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="fr-CA">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="es-ES">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="de-DE"><Script>Some javasript or jquery</Script></Text>
            <Text Culture="it-IT">34</Text>             
      </Route>  
        </Answer>               
            <Text Culture="en-CA">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="fr-CA">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="es-ES">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="de-DE">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="it-IT">34</Text>     
</Xflow>
```

and this is what I'm looking to achieve.  The order of the nodes in the output must remain the same as the original, and nested code must be maintained.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Survey Id="y77343555"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance.xsd" >
<Xflow>
    <Answer Code="4">
        <NewNode>
            <Text Culture="en-CA">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="fr-CA">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="es-ES">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="de-DE">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="it-IT">34</Text>
        </NewNode>
    </Answer>   
        <NewNode>
            <InstructionText Culture="en-CA">34</InstructionText>
            <InstructionText Culture="fr-CA">34</InstructionText>
            <InstructionText Culture="es-ES">34</InstructionText>
            <InstructionText Culture="de-DE"><Script>Some javasript or jquery</script></InstructionText>
            <InstructionText Culture="it-IT">34</InstructionText>
        </NewNode>          
    <Answer Code="45">
        <Route Code="12">
            <NewNode>
            <Text Culture="en-CA">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="fr-CA">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="es-ES">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="de-DE">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="it-IT">34</Text>
            </NewNode>
      </Route>  
        </Answer>   
            <NewNode>
            <Text Culture="en-CA">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="fr-CA">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="es-ES">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="de-DE">34</Text>
            <Text Culture="it-IT">34</Text>
        </NewNode>
</Xflow>
</Survey>
```

Any help on this would be greatfully received.  Thank you for looking

```
 :-)
```

Comment: Hi, I think thats the thing you are looking for; https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html

Comment: Very useful thank you, will try one of those methods

Comment: Can you explain the difference between your input XML and the desired output XML? Based on the samples shared, both the XMLs are same (maybe a copy-paste issue).

Comment: Arrrgggh.  -10 for me, I took a phone call and then lost the plot.  The node  <NewNode> </NewNode> should not exist in the first sample at all.  Thank you for pointing that out.